# Using the SIGINT signal without a callback in C

Tags: c, signals

I have a simple program that initializes two structures within my main method. I want to add a signal event handler for when the user presses ctrl-c to free the two structs I have allocated.

The issues is I do not want to make these two structures global variables, is there any way of calling the signal function with an inline callback?

Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //initialize structs

    signal(SIGINT, {
        //free structs on ctrl-c
    });
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Succinctly, No.  The kernel needs the address of a function that it can call as a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can't do precisely what you're asking for.

There are, of course, other ways to avoid making these variables global while achieving the same end. Whether it's worthwhile doing so depends on the circumstances. Here's an obvious way by registering the stuff you want to `free()` with a utility function, and calling that from your signal handler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 100

struct mystruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

enum manage_action {
    MYSTRUCT_STORE,
    MYSTRUCT_FREE
};

void manage_allocs(void * p, enum manage_action act)
{
    static void * ptr_stack[STACK_SIZE];
    static int top = 0;

    switch ( act ) {
        case MYSTRUCT_STORE:
            if ( top == STACK_SIZE ) {
                perror("Stack overflow");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            ptr_stack[top++] = p;
            break;

        case MYSTRUCT_FREE:
            for ( int i = 0; i < top; ++i ) {
                free(ptr_stack[i]);
            }
            top = 0;
            break;
    }
}

void handler(int dummy)
{
    manage_allocs(NULL, MYSTRUCT_FREE);
}

int main(void) {
    struct mystruct * a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    struct mystruct * b = malloc(sizeof *b);
    if ( !a || !b ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    manage_allocs(a, MYSTRUCT_STORE);
    manage_allocs(b, MYSTRUCT_STORE);

    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

`free()` is not guaranteed to be async-safe (neither is the `manage_allocs()` function in its entirety, for that matter), so the normal caveats about calling it from a signal handler are going to apply, and making sure that it'll never be re-entered.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel has to have a pointer to a function that it can call when the signal is received.  That cannot be an inline function, therefore.

Hence the succinct answer to your question is:

## No

Answer (score 0):

I agree that I don't see a way not use a global variable if your "simple" program 
consists of a single threaded, single .c source file.

However, if you are willing to allow a global variable whose scope is limited to a single source, you could use multiple .c sources (say main.c & sig.c)... i.e. put your signal handler, and a signal installer function in sig.c... the 'installer' will be called with the address to be free'd by the signal handler.  the 'installer' would save the address as a static global variable... which will limit its global scope to sig.c, while still making it available to the signal handler.

Granted this is still a global variable... but it is a "local global variable"...